# Composer install package in front of vendor folder not inside as a third party

Tags: php, composer-php

I am developing a PHP package and I have added a testing version to packagist so now I can install my package simply like this `composer require timino/timino dev-master` the package is installed correctly However the package is installed inside the vendor folder like so

```
timino
└── vendor
    ├── composer
    └── timino
        └── timino
            ├── App
            │ 
            └── pub
```

So it is completely different to my desired structure and in this case i need to point the `server root` to a very long path furthermore i need to generate another composer autoload  inside . so if it is possible i want to let composer install the package outside vendor to look exactly the same as my local version of the project like so

```
   timino
    ├── App // business logic
    │   
    ├── pub  // public root dir for servers (apache or nginx)
    │
    └── vendor // 3rd party
```

I have seen so far the [get composer website documentation on how to install a package in a custom location](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md) but i cant seem to find a practical example to my issue.

How can i let composer do so ? thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create a project based on `timino/timino`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
$ composer create-project timino/timino foo-bar-baz "dev-master"
```

to create a new project based on `timino/timino:dev-master` in the directory `foo-bar-baz`.

For reference, see:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project

#### Example

I ran

```
$ composer create-project timino/timino foo-bar-baz "dev-master"
```

which results in

```
Installing timino/timino (dev-master 3db1cda092af6bdf9bdb754c353f97d7e3121141)
  - Installing timino/timino (dev-master master): Cloning master from cache
Created project in foo-bar-baz
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Do you want to remove the existing VCS (.git, .svn..) history? [Y,n]? Y
```

and then

```
$ tree -L 1 --dirsfirst foo-bar-baz
```

which results in

```
foo-bar-baz
├── App
├── pub
├── vendor
├── README.md
├── composer.json
└── composer.lock

3 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's exactly what i was looking for !